# Merge git branches where files were deleted on one branch and I don't want them to be

Tags: git

I've inherited a horrible repo and I want to know if I can even salvage it.

So origin/master looks like this:

- project/

  - sub-project-0/

    - a
    - b
  - sub-project-1/

    - c
    - d

Also on origin are two "feature branches" which look like this

origin/feature/work-on-0:

- project/

  - sub-project-0

    - a
    - b
    - **+e**
  - sub-project-1

    - c
    - <s>-d</s>

Essentially they didn't JUST make changes to sub-project-0, they also just removed files from sub-project-1. This was done systematically as well, and the branch for adding features to sub-project-1 also has this issue.

I would like to merge everything into master, is there a way to tell git while merging to take the version of `d` here from master even though it isn't modified and technically doesn't conflict with anything?

Comment: it could be easier to let it merge and then check out the version of 'd' from the correct commit of the 'master' branch.

Comment: Yeah except d is a lot of different files and I don't feel like figuring out the pattern for them

Comment: I guess you would need to figure out all different patterns in any case, using any strategy. if this is as simple as not to allow missing files to be carry over, you either can play with file lists, using something like 'git ls-files' or create your own merging script which will check for missing files first, based on .gitattributes as in the BugHunter's awser. You can apply it to *all* files.

Answer (score 1):

You can create **.gitatributes** file for that purpose. Inside it you have to define which files you want to leave untouched during merge by specifying correct merge strategy.

Read more here:
[Git attributes - merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies)

Comment: this will not work with fast-forward allowed. So, disable fast-forward merge as well.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately in this case it seemed that Serge was right and in fact and it was easier to just checkout the correct versions of files before committing the merge.

In this case it was just

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit feature/work-on-0
git checkout HEAD -- sub-project-1/
```

which preserved d, and allowed it to not conflict with feature/work-on-1.

I looked at the .gitattributes solution but it didn't seem to be having the desired effect.

One issue was that there was no merging to do when feature/work-on-0 is merged in, it's just a fast-forward and master has no changes, but once feature/work-on-1 is merged onto that, then I want to keep some of theirs and some of ours depending on the folder.